# LZ77 and LZ78 differences in dictionaries

Tags: compression, lzw, lz77

you can find in many sources this statement regarding LZ77 and LZ78.

> They are both theoretically dictionary coders. LZ77 maintains a
> sliding window during compression. This was equivalent to the
> explicit dictionary constructed by LZ78 however, they are only
> equivalent when the entire data is intended to be decompressed.

I have difficulties understanding this, in the text mentioned, equivalency of an LZ77 to LZ78 (explicit dictionary).
Could anybody explain it?